How to Generate getName() for Enum Classes in OpenAPI 3.0?
I'm working with OpenAPI 3.0 and have defined a reusable Enum schema in my YAML configuration as follows:
components:
  schemas:
    Color:
      type: integer
      enum: [1, 2, 3]
      x-enum-varnames:
        - black
        - white
        - red

The generated Enum class correctly includes values and a getValue() method. However, I need to send the Enum name (e.g., "black", "white", "red") as part of the API response, not just the integer value. I'm looking for a way to have OpenAPI automatically generate a getName() method or similar for this purpose.
Is there a configuration option or a modification I can make in the OpenAPI spec to enable this? How can I instruct the generator to include both names and values in the Enum class?
Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Looks like you should use @ApiModelProperty inside your DTO's field (or entity, depending on your project) and @ApiModel on top of both the entity's class and the enum. This way, OpenAPI should recognize your Enum!
For further information, you can check out this link!
If you are not using annotations to build the Swagger, check out this link instead!
